# Adding to a python dictionary, is clearing the dictionary, then adding

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pickle

I am trying to make a password manager... and it keeps clearing the dictionary then adding the key whenever you try to add a new password

```py
q1 = input("yes/no: ")                                                                                                                                                                            
    if q1 == "yes":                                                                                                                                                                                   
        print("please make vault password?")                                                                                                                                                          
        pass = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password:', stream=None)                                                                                                                                      
        with open("src/o", "wb") as op:                                                                                                                                                               
            q2 = input("website used on: ")                                                                                                                                                           
            o[q2] = p                                                                                                                                                                                 
            print(o)                                                                                                                                                                                  
            o = pickle.dump(o,op,protocol=2)                                                                                                                                                          
        with open("src/o", "br") as opp:                                                                                                                                                              
            print(pickle.load(opp))
```

Comment: Have you opened it in append mode?

Comment: @Akshit Achara No I have not, how would I append bytes is it just 'ab'?

Comment: I am not sure but you can find it in the documentation

Comment: I looked it up and tried it and it did the same thing

Comment: The variable `o` is used before we see it being defined (`o[q2]=p`).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your pickled object every time. Also your code's logic is a bit messed up. Try the following:

```py
q1 = input("yes/no: ")
if q1 == "yes":

  # get user info
  print("please make vault password?")
  given_website = input("website used on: ")   
  given_pass = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password:', stream=None) 

  # open the vault
  with open("src/o", "br") as vault:
    o = pickle.load(vault) 
    # store the new data in the vault
    o[given_website] = given_pass

  # close the vault
  with open("src/o", "wb") as vault:
    pickle.dump(o, vault, protocol=2)
```